# PHP Array of arrays of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to search this array by the value of ['field'] and then return the value of ['value'] associated with that field in the array.

For example, I want to say "Tell me the value associated with theThirdField".

I've tried many, many permutations of something like the following:
$myVariable = $Array['result']['totalrows'][0]['rownum'][0]['field'];

To further clarify, I will never know which order / sub-array my search field is located in, I only know the string value associated with ['field'].

How would I accomplish this?

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [totalrows] => 1
            [rows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [rownum] => 1
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [field] => testMeOnce
                                            [value] => 436586498
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [field] => testMeTwice
                                            [value] => 327698034
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [field] => theThirdField
                                            [value] => 108760374
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [field] => theFourthField
                                            [value] => 2458505
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [field] => fifthField
                                            [value] => -0.0201
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Do you have some error when try to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you expect something like that?

```
$needle = 'theThirdField'; // searched field name
$valuesArray = $Array['result']['rows'][0]['values']; //now you have clearer array

array_walk($valuesArray, function($element, $key) use ($needle) {
    if ($element['field'] == $needle) {
        echo $element['value'];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, assuming you want to search only in the $myVariable  dimension :

```
$myVariable = $Array['result']['rows'][0]['values'];

foreach ($myVariable as $key => $value) {
    if( $value['field'] === 'theThirdField' ) { 
        echo $value['value']; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when I ran your code, I got some syntax errors. I have changed your Array to this (changed syntax only):

```
$a = Array
    (
        'result' =>
            [
                'totalrows' => 1,
                'rows' =>
                    [
                        0 =>
                            [
                                'rownum' => 1,
                                'values' =>
                                    [
                                        0 => 
                                            [
                                                'field' => 'testMeOnce',
                                                'value' => 436586498
                                            ],

                                        1 => 
                                            [
                                                'field' => 'testMeTwice',
                                                'value' => 327698034
                                            ],

                                        2 => 
                                            [
                                                'field' => 'theThirdField',
                                                'value' => 108760374
                                            ],

                                        3 => 
                                            [
                                                'field' => 'theFourthField',
                                                'value' => 2458505
                                            ],

                                        4 => 
                                            [
                                                'field' => 'fifthField',
                                                'value' => -0.0201
                                            ]

                                    ]

                            ]

                    ]

            ]

    );
```

now you can get the value like this:

```
print($a['result']['rows'][0]['values'][2]['value']); // --> 108760374
```

I hope that this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I used a mix of your suggestions and ended up doing the following:

```
$valuesArray = $Array['result']['rows'][0]['values'];

foreach ($valuesArray as $value) {
    $fieldName = $value['field'];
    $$fieldName = $value['value'];
}
```

Since I know the names of all the fields I want, but not the order, this allowed me to capture all of the values of each field with the name of the field becoming the variable name.